# Why is there no way to refer to a single column in a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java 2D arrays and I tried searching it up online, but why is there no way to refer to a single column in a 2D array(java)?
I know you can refer to a single row with arrayName[r] or a specific element, but it seems you can't do it for a column?

Comment: You can refer column with arr[i][j], i denotes row and j denotes column in that row.

Comment: That's not a reference to an entire column, it's a reference to one element.

Comment: Row or columns are implementation specific concepts. Java uses more abstract concepts. Row or column is only what you want to call to *array element indexes*, so you are using the wrong concepts, this is you cannot find the way to refer to columns. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: "Rows" are atomic units from an array perspective.  "Columns" are pieces of each of those units at the same index.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero - indeed. I habitually use `array[row][column]`, but it could be the other way round.  My convention is the reverse of a cartesian approach, `array[x_coord][y_coord]`, which may be more natural in other situations.

Comment: [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/3404097)

Answer (score 6):

There are no actual 2D arrays in Java.

There are only arrays of arrays.

What you call a 'column' is a one element from each of many arrays.  And that's why a column is not a single entity.

Comment: But it is possible to do so with rows?

Comment: If you're indexing like `array[row][column]` then `array[row]` is a row.

Comment: Oh ok I see now. Only rows can be called like that